Pygame sprite post-collision mouvemnt
I've made it so when the sprites of player1 and player2 collide, the code stops taking input and they do not move. I've been having trouble implementing the movement if the input after the collision is opposite to the direction of the collision, so that when the two sprites collide they don't overlap and can move away from eachother.
This is as far as I got on this snippet of my code:
 keys1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pygame.Rect.colliderect(player1.rect, player2.rect) == False:
        player1.update(keys1)
    else: (continue moving if input diretion is opposite to collision direction)
        


Depending on your game, you might still want the players to be able to press keys while colliding (for example if in melee combat of some kind), but this is for you to refactor.
I would suggest learning how games of old handled this. for example, mario 64 famously does each move in 4 steps, and after each steps checks if the next one would make mario collide with a wall. As a hobby developer, you can get away with doing only one step, or even simply allowing the rects to temporarly overlab, but then push each other backwards so they're barely not touching:
p1.update(keys)
p2.update(keys)
if collide(p1.rect, p.rect):
    #we make the inverse of the vector between p1 and p2's centers
    between_centers = pygame.math.Vector2(p2.rect.center.x - p1.rect.center.x, p2.rect.center.y - p1.rect.center.y)
    #we scale that vector by half, to make each player be reppelled by the same amount
    between_centers.scale_to_length(between_centers.length/2)
    
    #we move p1 backwards
    p1.rect.move_ip(between_centers.x, between_centers.y)

    #we invert the vector, to push p2 in the opposite direction
    between_centers.rotate_ip(180)
    p2.rect.move_ip(between_centers.x, between_centers.y)


note that this doesn't take in consideration an eventual ground below the players, so assume this is for a top-down game, like Enter The Gungeon.
as a general rule of thumb, it's easier to allow the player objects to temporarly (less than 1 frame!) intersect and fix it later, rather than preventing them from taking the action in the first place. this is because player input might not be the only thing making changes to their position, for example you could imagine taking damage or shooting a powerful weapon would also update their position regardless of whether they pressed keys or not.
